# Edición de usuarios usando la gema Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Estoy usando la gema Devise de Ruby on Rails pero voy un poco lento ya que es algo confusa.

Cuando un usuario edita su propio perfil, de manera predeterminada Devise le dice que deje en blando la contraseña (contraseña y confirmación de contraseña) si no la quiere cambiar.  Además le pide la contraseña actual para poder cambiarla.  Cómo puedo hacer que el administrador edite los perfiles de los otros usuarios manteniendo ese mismo comportamiento?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Podrías usar como base el mismo template de edición de contraseña [que usa devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/passwords/edit.html.erb). Ahora cómo lo implementas para que un administrador lo pueda editar, eso solo lo sabes tú, ya que solo tú conoces como es tu interfaz de administrador. Si no has implementado nada, te puedo aconsejar usar activeadmin o rails_admin para que un admin pueda acceder a editar no solo los datos de usuario, sino que de las tablas que tu elijas.

Comment: Eso intenté, pero cuando trato de editar un usuario regular con el usuario administrador y no quiero modificar la contraseña, igual me muestra la validación diciendo que la contraseña no puede estar en blanco.

Comment: Entonces agrega a tu pregunta el código con el cual estás tratando de editar el usuario

Answer (score 0):

Si cambias configuracion predeterminada de devise para que te permita utilizar el mismo controlador con funcionalidades diferentes o extendidas según este logueado un usuario con un rol específico podras proveer a tu aplicación una funcionalidad para lograr que tu admin dejé algunos campos en blanco.

Comment: la zona de respuestas no es espacio adecuado para pedirle aclaraciones o mejoras a su pregunta al OP, favor de leer [answer]

Comment: Bueno, en este momento tengo un modelo llamado User que utilizo tanto para lo usuarios administradores como los usuarios regulares.  Además creé un controlador aparte para llamado regular_users_contoller para administrar la lógica de los usuarios regulares, pero en él utilizo el mismo modelo User. Empezando por ahí, cuál sería la manera correcta?  debo usar el mismo controlador de devise o está bien que separe la lógica en otro controlador?

Comment: Pido sinceras disculpas por utilizar el espacio de respuestas para tratar de dar un poco de contexto a mi respuesta.

Comment: Imagino que podrías indicarnos que validaciones tienes activas en el módulo y en los controladores para saber cómo tienes configuradas las vistas y que información estás solicitando cómo predeterminada en los formularios.

Comment: Deberías colocar modificar el contenido de la pregunta y adicionar el código que ya has desarrollandola... Esto nos proveerá de un mayor contexto en tu problema.